# Make an hard figure in html, css

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

How can i make this figure as one div in css ? Not svg!

**Figure is here :**

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
  <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="stroke:black;fill:khaki;stroke-width:1px;"  d="M140.874 308.014 141.874 158.014 234.926 157.015 234.874 106.014 287.926 105.014 287.874 54.0144 377.874 54.0144 379.374 182.014 548.874 182.014 548.874 309.014z" transform="matrix(1.05374 0 0 1 -4.94393 0)"/>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with linear-gradient and drop-shadow filter for the border:

```css
.box {
  height:200px;
  width:300px;
  background:
  linear-gradient(khaki,khaki) 40% 100%/20% 84% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(khaki,khaki) 20% 100%/20% 70% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(khaki,khaki) 0 100%/50% 50% no-repeat,
  linear-gradient(khaki,khaki) 100% 100%/50% 40% no-repeat;
  filter:drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px #000);
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Or the classic *ugly* way using pseudo-element and border:

```css
.box {
  margin-top: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  background: khaki;
  position: relative;
  border:1px solid;
}

.box:before,
.box:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}
.box:before {
   right:120px;
   bottom:100px;
   width:70px;
   height:70px;
   background:khaki;
   border-right:1px solid;
   border-top:1px solid;
   border-left:1px solid;
}
.box:after {
   right:191px;
   bottom:100px;
   width:60px;
   height:40px;
   background:khaki;
   border-top:1px solid;
   border-left:1px solid;
}
.box span{
   position:absolute;
   left:-1px;
   bottom:100px;
   width:49px;
   height:20px;
   background:khaki;
   border-top:1px solid;
   border-left:1px solid;
   z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: @CristianCănănău remove the filter :)

Comment: i mean like to make this element as one figure without sapce ?

Comment: @CristianCănănău what browser are you using ?

Comment: google chrom and IE why? i mean like https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwsHI.png without that space

Comment: @CristianCănănău but this is html :) everything is rectangular, there is no way to have a non rectangular element .. even your path is like that if you inspect the elemen

Comment: soo i can't make anything ?

Comment: @CristianCănănău why you bother your self with something like this ? this is how HTML/CSS work, since you have the element you need, then what is the issue ? ... you canno change how the element works, and even if there is a way to remive this space, what will be the plus ? nothing i guess

Comment: i am making something else and there i move element in this box by using jquery draggable and there is an option contain soo if i move an element inside then i willl move it outside of this box, but i need it inside.

Comment: @CristianCănănău you can told me this instead :) and i will understand then

Comment: sorry for that i thought this is not important, i thought that what i want is possible thats why.

Comment: @CristianCănănău it can be possible ;) i will try to adjust ... by the way the second solution i provided will do what you want ;)

Comment: ok thx of lot for that i will accept then the answer, if you will have another option for me then past it here.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this shape with the CSS [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) property by using the `polygon` function. The border can be simulated with a drop shadow in all 4 directions, applied to a wrapper element:

```css
.shape {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background: khaki;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 100%, 0% 40%, 20% 40%, 20% 15%, 40% 15%, 40% 0%, 60% 0%, 60% 50%, 100% 50%, 100% 100%);
}

.wrapper {
  filter: drop-shadow(1px 1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(1px -1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(-1px 1px 0px black)
    drop-shadow(-1px -1px 0px black);
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="shape"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

For make div in this form you can use 'clip-path' like this example:

```css
.test{
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
  background: red;
  clip-path: polygon(140.874px 308.014px, 141.874px 158.014px, 234.926px 157.015px, 234.874px 106.014px, 287.926px 105.014px, 287.874px 54.0144px, 377.874px 54.0144px, 379.374px 182.014px, 548.874px 182.014px, 548.874px 309.014px);
}
```

```html
<div class="test"></div>
```

But this CSS rule doesn't work in IE and Edge.

Comment: better use % value wilth clip-path or you will have to adjust all the values when changing the width/height

Comment: Yes, I agree. I for an example used parameters from SVG in a question.